# Gmail Authentication using XOAuth 2.0

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, gmail

I want to implement XOAuth 2.0 for my web application in Java.

My application asks for username and password from the user. Now using these credentials I want to authenticate the user through Gmail.

Please suggest libraries, and also how to implement it??
I am new to authentication using Gmail. Need some suggestions.

Comment: [ stormpath ]: https://stormpath.com/product/api-authentication/

Answer (score -1):

as I know the purpose of the OAuth 2.0 is to prevent leak of the user's credentials into 3rd party applications.

The [abstract flow shows](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.2) how client (3rd party app) should use the `access_token` (retrieved with one of the grant types) to access resource.

The specification also defines the basic HTTPS calls to use for example in case of an [authorization code grant type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1) (I think this flow best suits for you). This has 2 request, one for the `code` (user agent redirection is used to send the code to the 3rd party app) and one for the `access_token`.

Authorization code request&response

```
 GET /authorize?response_type=code&client_id=s6BhdRkqt3&state=xyz
        &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fclient%2Eexample%2Ecom%2Fcb HTTP/1.1
 Host: server.example.com

 HTTP/1.1 302 Found
 Location: https://client.example.com/cb?code=SplxlOBeZQQYbYS6WxSbIA
               &state=xyz
```

Token request&response:

```
 POST /token HTTP/1.1
 Host: server.example.com
 Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 grant_type=authorization_code&code=SplxlOBeZQQYbYS6WxSbIA
 &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fclient%2Eexample%2Ecom%2Fcb

 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
 Cache-Control: no-store
 Pragma: no-cache

 {
   "access_token":"2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAA",
   "token_type":"example",
   "expires_in":3600,
   "refresh_token":"tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA",
   "example_parameter":"example_value"
 }
```

So you do not need to ask a user for the GMail credentials.

[Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth) you can find a spring-security example for an OAuth 2.0 compliant application.

I hope I could help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I just wanted to add something, my application do not have any process to authenticate whether a user is valid or not like storing passwords or some thing like that.So, I need to go with his gmail credentials to authenticate him. Now, for the above token, what I understood is access_tokens are application specific then how a user is authenticated, it' will be the application who gets authenticated.Please correct if I misunderstood something.And responses are always welcomed.

Comment: And I don't want to do any operations outside my application.I just want to check whether user is valid or not, I mean holding the account or not.

Comment: I understand. This quick-start app can help you build a "sign-in" button with Google. https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/java